# Disable a sign-out button in android app for a time and take time from server for time

Tags: android

I want to disable a button in app so that no one can sign-out and gps location can be traced. 
i was using this code and it went in infinite loop and now it is not logging out

```
private void logoutWebService(String systemId, String imei, String lat, String lng) {

    AppPreference preferences = AppPreference.getInstance(Dashboard.this);
    String distanceValue = preferences.getString(PrefConstant.ODOMETER, "");

    //
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long previousTime = prefs.getLong("time", 0);
    long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    // 30*60*1000 - 30 min, each with 60 sec, each with 1000 millisec
    if (LoginActivity.logintime - currentTime > 2*60*1000){

        //enable the button
        Logout logoutStatus = new Logout(HttpConstant.LOGOUT_URL + "SYSID=" + systemId + "&IMEI=" + imei + "&DATETIME=" + AppUtility.dateTime() + "&LAT=" + lat + "&LNG=" + lng + "&ODOMETER=" + distanceValue);

        Logout.setEnabled(true);
        logoutStatus.setProgressEnable(true);
        HttpConnectionUtil.callWebService(logoutStatus, this, WebserviceType.LOGOUT, mLogoutWebServiceCompleteListener);System.out.println("Logout .... " + logoutStatus.URL.toString());

    } else
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong("time", currentTime);
        editor.apply();
        signOut.setEnabled(false);
        //disable it and start a new CountdownTimer; this is needed in order for
        //it to to become enabled if you're still in the app and the time ran out
        signOut.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: what is the signout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private interface ResponseListener {
     void onSuccess();
     void onError();
}

public void sendLocation(Location location) {
    logoutButton.setEnabled(false);
    webService.yourCall(location, new ResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess {
            logoutButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError {
            logoutButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
     });
}
```

You have to add a callback to your service call. In your case this is inside your HttpConnectionUtils class. To give you a hint how you have to show me the code of your Utils class...

Comment: This isn't the code in the question... `HttpConnectionUtil.callWebService`... What is `sendLocation`? `ResponseListener`? Please explain the code

Comment: I updated my code. ResponseListener is an interface you have to write and call it's onSuccess method and probable also it's onError method depending on the http code you receive from your server

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If yes please also honor my commitment and mark this answer as correct